# Dynamically add tabs in Tablayoutpanle using UIBinder

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gxt, uibinder, gwt-tablayoutpanel

To be clear i'm a newbie to GWT.I was looking around for samples to implement dynamic tabs, and found this link, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/AddingnewtabdynamicallyExtGWT.htm , in which they make use of GXT.But my question is,how can i implement dynamic views using UIBinder?.I want to implement something similar to browser tabs.Each newly created tab has a split panel view, whose content will be populated making a rpc request.My question is , how is the history mechanism handled when user switches between tabs?.Can anyone provide with samples?Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You declare your TabLayoutPanel together with the initial/default tabs in UiBinder. Then you can add or remove tabs from this panel in your Java code.

Comment: Even i had a similar approach.See my edited answer.I wanted tablayoutpanel to look something like browser tabs.